# Get mouse to specific color pixel?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, maps, gis

Is there a way, perhaps using selenium, to make the mouse pointer get to and hover over a specific color pixel?
I'm trying to get my mouse to get to the pixel in green/white:
[image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOFv6.png) I'm trying this to be able to extract the coordinates of each point.

The site uses GIS cloud.

Comment: can you inspect the said element in the map div? Did you find any selector there like id or class?

Comment: @SwaroopHumane no, I don't think there's any selector, unfortunately. I believe the map is only divided via "leaflets". However, here's the site if you'd like to take a look: https://cartocritica.giscloud.com/

Comment: https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is more a concept question.

**1** Selenium can to to an element with `ActionChains`

```
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element("your_locator")
    actions.click().perform()
```

**2** Selenium can get a pixel color with `value_of_css_property` function.

```
element_color = your_locator.value_of_css_property("background-image")
```

I don't really think that you will need to get elements color. You should find its css or xpath locator and move to it with `ActionChains`.

So, **ActionChains** is what you really need.

Comment: Thanks! However, the problem is, I believe, that my points are not accessible programmatically. In this case, there would be no way to locate the points to use the methods you've given me?

Comment: If your points are browser elements,  they are accessible.

Comment: They’re embedded into a dynamic GIS map. Via inspect, I find no trace of them, given that they change given your selection.

Comment: In this case, ca you share the site?

Comment: Sure! The site is: [link](https://cartocritica.giscloud.com/)

Comment: Describe in manual steps what you want to verify

Comment: For each row that appears on the bottom table: Select a row -> this highlights a point -> get my mouse pointer to the highlighted point (this changes the coordinates on the map) -> extract the coordinates

Comment: It's not always possible to use CSS because one does not always know exactly which element is of the color expected.  For instance, if it's SVG it could use "fill", while if it's HTML it could use background-color.   The user sees something on the screen change color but finding that element is unreliable because it needs to be based on what the user sees, which doesn't change, versus the web page implementation  which can.  Getting a specific pixel color relative to the element position where known text is found seems the only way.